# I have a hungarian text ISO-8859-2 and I would the text read into a file but does not work in Python3

Tags: python

The code here is:

```
f = open('nametext','r')
print(f)
f.close()
```

but when I look at the print, there is not what I want:

```
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='nametext' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>
```

This is the message, but I want the text what it is in the file, like this:

```
Bevallás iparûzési adófeltöltési kötelezettségről 2013  
Gépjármûadó-kedvezmény mentesség bevallás 2013  
Helyi iparûzési adóbevallás 2013    
Idegenforgalmi adóbevallás 2013 
Kommunális adóbevallás 2013 
Talajterhelési díj bevallás 2013
```

What the problem is?

Comment: BTW, if the encoding isn't UTF-8 you need to mention that when opening the file, eg `f = open('nametext', 'r', encoding='latin2')`

Answer (score 2):

As was mentioned in the comments, you need to `.read()` the file:

```
with open('nametext','r') as f:
    print(f.read())
```